# Rails: is it safe to use this style of before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have simple app, but I'm caring about confidencial of users data.
Is it safe to use this type of verifying?

```
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]

def authenticate
  redirect_to(root_path) unless !current_user.nil?
end
def correct_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user == User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the filters are generally safe but I cant vouch for your login management and how you identify users. If someone manages to break the `current_user` method then there could be some issues, however if the authentication code is from Devise, Authlogic or a well maintained gem then you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Also you may want to look into managing your permissions with [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). Defining cases like this is easy and there is a central file that is used to manage all the permissions so you can keep your code flexible.

Comment: Thanks! I have authentication method from railscasts'270 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1). I hope, it's no bad solution :)

Comment: Sure, thats not a bad solution. I would reccomend you take a look at cancan if you are interested. Its written by Ryan Bates the same guy who does the Railscasts.